# add a domain end of string with regex

Tags: regex, replace, dns, addition

I learned that, if else is possible in regex. 
I want to add domain if a given word is not end up with a domain.

For example,

if given word `stack.xyxy.com` is, regex pass, does nothing. But if given word stack is, 
regex must give me the result stack.xyxy.com. I want to add a domain end of text.

I wana do it with pcre regex, but I don't use it in php, searched many variations in regex101.com, but couldn't be successfull.

Thanks.

Comment: Something like this? https://regex101.com/r/yO6hH5/1

Answer (score 0):

You can use look-ahead for this. Try this:

```
stack(?=\.xyxy\.com)
```

Here's a working example on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oY2oY6/1)

For more information on look-ahead, check out this [guide](http://regex%20lookahead%20and%20lookbehind%20together). `Look-ahead` is supported in PCRE implementations and in most popular languages.

Answer (score 0):

maybe I can not explain correctly.

if given word is a domain, regex must do nothing, if given word is not a domain, regex must add domain name end of the given word.

for example, 
given word = stack.xyxy.com -- passs
given word = stack -- regex must return, give me the result stack.xyxy.com.

is it possible with regex ?